# IllegalStateException - removeView() in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, removechild

I am trying to get working my Fragment with ViewPager but I am getting this error:

**LogCat:**

```
12-19 14:16:25.180: I/mFragment(5866): onCreate() LogicAnalizerActivity
12-19 14:16:25.235: I/mFragment(5866): FragmentAdapter Constructor
12-19 14:16:25.235: I/mFragment(5866): onResume() LogicAnalizerActivity
12-19 14:16:25.310: I/mFragment(5866): Page item 0
12-19 14:16:25.320: I/onCreate()(5866): onCreate LogicAnalizerView
12-19 14:16:25.350: D/AndroidRuntime(5866): Shutting down VM
12-19 14:16:25.355: W/dalvikvm(5866): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d77300)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3378)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3249)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3194)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3170)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:874)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2432)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4978)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
12-19 14:16:25.690: E/AndroidRuntime(5866):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**ActivityFragment:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;

public class LogicAnalizerActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;
    /** Numero de paginas del ViewPager */
    private static final int pageCount = 1;

    private static ActionBar actionBar;
    private static ViewPager mViewPager;
    private static MyFragmentAdapter mAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        if(DEBUG) Log.i("mFragment","onCreate() LogicAnalizerActivity");

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment);

        mAdapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerLogicAnalizer);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if(DEBUG) Log.i("mFragment","onResume() LogicAnalizerActivity");
        super.onResume();
    }

    /**
     * Crea el ActionBar desde el XML actionbarlogic que define los iconos en el mismo
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if(DEBUG) Log.i("onCreateOptionsMenu()", "onCreateOptionsMenu() -> LogicAnalizerView");
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbarlogic, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public static class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            if(DEBUG) Log.i("mFragment","FragmentAdapter Constructor");
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            if(DEBUG) Log.i("mFragment","Page item " + arg0);
            switch(arg0){
                case 0:
                    return new LogicAnalizerFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new LogicAnalizerFragment();
            }
            return new LogicAnalizerFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return pageCount;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
            if(DEBUG) Log.i("mFragment","Destroy item " + position);
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((LinearLayout) view);
        }

    }
}
```

---

**LogicAnalizerFragment:**
It is too long, you can see it [here](https://github.com/dragondgold/MultiWork/blob/master/src/com/multiwork/andres/LogicAnalizerFragment.java)

---

**Fragment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pagerLogicAnalizer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Fragment is correctly working, but when I try to use it with ViewPager I am getting this error, I have searched a lot of ViewPager examples and all are the same. I have added:

```
            @Override
            public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
                if(DEBUG) Log.i("mFragment","Destroy item " + position);
                ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((LinearLayout) view);
            }
```

to try to solve the problem but it persists.

Comment: How does the `LogicAnalizerFragment` fragment looks like?

Comment: It is too long to put it here, you can see it here https://github.com/dragondgold/MultiWork/blob/master/src/com/multiwork/andres/LogicAnalizerFragment.java

Comment: In the `onCreateView` method of the fragment you should have `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.logicanalizer, container, false);`

Comment: With return inflater.inflate(R.layout.logicanalizer, container,false); it is partially working!! :D But when I go to the right everything is ok, but when I go back I get the same error :/

Comment: In your sample you have `pageCount` as `1` so you should have just one fragment. Also you should remove your override of `destroyItem`.

Comment: I have changed the number to 3, I will try removing destroyItem.

Comment: Also remove your return new LogicAnalizerFragment(); after the switch.

Comment: But I need a return or a default: in my switch

Comment: Oh , right. I usually return something else or an erorr, to tell myself something has gone wrong and the args0 is not in the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 250,

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.logicanalizer, container);
```

add false;

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.logicanalizer, container,false);
```

the 3rd params determins weather it should be attached to the 'container' or not, documents:

> @3rd param attachToRoot   Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the
>   root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the correct
>   subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.
>
> @return The root View of the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied
>   and attachToRoot is true, this is root; otherwise it is the root of
>   the inflated XML file.

Comment: With return inflater.inflate(R.layout.logicanalizer, container,false); it is partially working!! :D But when I go to the right everything is ok, but when I go back I get the same error :/